# Get variable from parent

Tags: python

I have two files. main.py that has main program logic and functions.py that has additional functions. Lets say main.py has this code

```
import functions
some_var = 'some value'
```

I would like to print out value of some_var in my functions.py file. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can do this my simply importing the `main` module within `functions.py`

Within your functions.py file:

```
import main
print main.some_var
```

However, you currently have a circular dependency problem.  See [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-cyclic-imports)

You *could* put `some_var` into a third module, let's say `constants.py` and then `main.py` would look like:

```
import functions
from constants import some_var
... etc
```

and `functions.py` would be:

```
from constants import some_var
```

Solving your circular dependency problem.